# Read data-set and add it to double quotes

Tags: python, pandas, list

```
Scott Logistics Corp
Transportation One LLC
Brothers Logistics Inc
Western Express Inc
Dart Advantage Logistics
Western Express Inc
Western Express Inc
Landstar Inway
Circle Logistics Inc
```

See above data set i want to add each name in a double quotes e.g ("Scott Logistics Corp") or see below what i wanted to do with this dataset.

```
"Scott Logistics Corp"
"Transportation One LLC"
"Brothers Logistics Inc"
"Western Express Inc"
"Dart Advantage Logistics"
"Western Express Inc"
"Western Express Inc"
"Landstar Inway"
"Circle Logistics Inc"
....
```

I will be reading data from the dataset-1 which is in .txt file and want to change it to the dataset-2 each name in double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add double quotes then pure python is plenty:

```
with open(r"text_1.txt",'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = re.sub(r'\n','',line)
        lines_new = (f'"{line}\"\n')
        with open("text_2.txt", "a") as f1:
            f1.writelines(lines_new)



"Scott Logistics Corp"
"Transportation One LLC"
"Brothers Logistics Inc"
"Western Express Inc"
"Dart Advantage Logistics"
"Western Express Inc"
"Western Express Inc"
"Landstar Inway"
"Circle Logistics Inc"
```